# Java - Math Calculations - BigDecimal

Tags: java, android, math, bigdecimal

My question is related to math and how one should go about calculating "financial" mathematical equations with Java with emphasis on Android development. According to Philip Barker✝ the author of "Java Methods for Financial Engineering" developers should take special care with regards to **accuracy** and **error** when dealing with **numerical approximations**. Below is a quote from his book which should make things clearer for this discussion.

> "Since we are largely dealing with numeric approximations or iterative
>   convergence to a desired solution the discussion of accuracy and error
>   are important.
>
> In the decimal system irrational (e.g. √2) and transcendental (e.g.
>   ) numbers cannot have a precise representation, most rational
>   numbers are also not represented precisely, in decimal notation.
>   Representing 1∕3 as a decimal can be approximated by 0.3 or
>   0.333333333 or some other arbitrarily large representation. Providing a decimal value for 1∕3, means representing the division as a floating
>   point number.”

In order to make things simpler for development my question is the following:

1- Given that I know what my calculations should expect with regards to **"scale"** and **"precision"**✝ are there any drawbacks from making all calculations within my app with BigDecimal type? I want to keep things simple and this seems to work as far as financial equations are concerned (e.g. ROI, Compound Interest Rate, etc…). What do you think?

2- I noticed that the core Java library does not provide methods for calculating BigDecimals when the answer falls within the "irrational" or "transcendental" spectrum. This is probably because Sun or Oracle decided to leave the “burden of proof” to the developer to extend in its own application what is considered to be acceptable in terms of numerical accuracy. However, I discovered a BigBecimal library that seems to implement most of the methods omitted in the core library related to irrational and transcendental numbers. Its a library found at the Cornell University Library… you can get there by clicking [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3030v2) or here for the [files](http://arxiv.org/src/0908.3030v2/anc). Would this library allow me to calculate financial equations without having to cast outside BigDecimal type except at the result toString()?

Any feedback on these questions would be highly appreciated.

✝ His book is a great read if you are interested in Java Financial Math.

✝✝ If you are unfamiliar with “scale & precision” you can read a great answer here.

Comment: Can you post some of the code you have tried?

Comment: You do understand that there are infinitely many real numbers, but your computer has finitely many states with which to represent those numbers, right?

Comment: @DavidWallace...Yes I do. But for the sake of simplicity I would like to stick to a single "type" throughout the calculation...BigDecimal seems to take care of that specially since I know my scale and precision. What I wanted to know is if there is something I'm overlooking. From what I see one of the most important considerations for Java primitives and complex types has to do with memory management and given that I can set a MathContext with the right precision there does not seem to be a problem to my idea. Am I missing something? I'm just trying to be cautious and asking around for advice.

Comment: @JeffSloyer... Hi Jeff I have not implemented any code (only investigating for now) but just to give you some perspective you can download the file called BigDecimalMath.java on the link above and look for the pow() implementation. This library allows for the use of BigDecimal exponent which is not possible with the core libraries. Financial calculations often have decimal power exponents which force the developer to cast to a different type. Every time we switch type there is an inherited risk or loss of precision specially if we are calculating currency. Would you agree?

Comment: A good question is asked. I would love to know the answers from experts.